# Combine two DataTable Columns into one using Javascript

Tags: javascript, grails, groovy, datatables

I'm currently working with Groovy/Grails and Javascript.

The code I am currently working with doesn't seem to follow a standard of how DataTables are implemented (at least not what I can see; I'm new to using DataTables and I can't find anything that is similar to what I'm seeing)

I need to combine the Survey Name and Type columns into a single column. 
Example data within the "Survey Name / Type" column: "This is my Survey Name (Type)"

Controller:
The Table definitions are declared in the Controller. I'm not quite sure why they are defined here rather than on the gsp...

```
def impTableConfigs = [
        id:  [ title: '', sortIndex: 'id', visible: false ],
        surveyId: [ title: 'Survey ID Number', sortIndex: 'surveyId', visible: true ],
        surveyName: [ title:  'Survey Name', sortIndex: 'surveyName', visible: true],
        type: [ title:  'Survey Type', sortIndex: 'type.code', visible: true]
]

def imp = {
   // Check is user is logged in

   // Check the users role

    def dataMemberNames = getDataMemberNames(impTableConfigs)
    def editingShtuff = userService.getUserEditing()

    withFormat{
        html{
            return [
                    title: "Surveys",
                    editingShtuff : editingShtuff ,
                    selectedRefugeId: params.filter,
                    colNames: dataMemberNames,
                    colTitles: dataMemberNames.collect{
                        impTableConfigs[it]["title"]
                    }
            ]
        }
        json{
            def args = getListDataParams(impTableConfigs, dataMemberNames, editingShtuff)
            def results = getFormattedImpListData(
                    impTableConfigs,
                    editingShtuff ,
                    args.refuge,
                    args.max,
                    args.offset,
                    args.sort,
                    args.sortDir
            )
            render results as JSON
        }
    }
}
```

GSP

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var ops = {
            editAction:'${createLink(controller:"survey", action:"edit")}',
            source:'${createLink(controller:"report", action:"imp.json")}?filter='+$("#filter option:selected").val(),
            swfUrl:'${resource(dir:'css/data-tables-tabletools',file:'copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf')}',
            colNames:<%= colNames as JSON %>,
            selectable: false,
            useCache: false,
            csvAction: '${createLink(action:"imp_download_csv")}',
            pdfAction: '${createLink(action:"imp_download_pdf")}',
            csvParams: getFilterParam,
            pdfParams: getFilterParam
        };

        // Initialize dataTable
        var table = new primr.dataTable("#dataTable", ops, {
            aoColumnDefs: [ { aTargets: [8], bSortable: false }]
        });
        window.table = table;

        // Connect filter events
        $("#filter").change(function(){
            var filter = $("#filter option:selected").val();
            table.changeSource("${createLink(controller:"report", action:"imp.json")}?filter=" + filter);
        })
    });
```

HTML within the GSP

```
<table id="dataTable">
<thead>
<tr>
    <g:each in="${colTitles}" var="it" status="i">
        <th>${it}<sup>${i}</sup></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
```

I'm thinking I need to move the column definitions from the Controller to the GSP and put them in the aoColumnDefs and formatting the surveyName to concatonate the 2 columns together? I'm hesistent to do this, however, as the impTableConfigs variable is used in multiple methods within the Controller. (I've included one such method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I had already solved the issue but my browser was caching the domain object and controllers.

I put a getter in the Domain Object to concatonate the column values and put it in the impTableConfigs

```
def impTableConfigs = [
        id:  [ title: '', sortIndex: 'id', visible: false ],
        surveyId: [ title: 'Survey ID Number', sortIndex: 'surveyId', visible: true ],
        surveyNameAndType: [title: 'Survey Name/(Type)', sortIndex: 'surveyName', visible: true],
        //surveyName: [ title:  'Survey Name', sortIndex: 'surveyName', visible: true ],
        //type: [ title:  'Survey Type', sortIndex: 'type.code', visible: true ],           
]
```